# Remove reaction DiscordBot

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord bot that puts roles based on which emoji you choose. Up to here it works well, but what I want to do is always keep the emoji counter always at 1 and if a user presses the button the role is assigned and if he represses it the role will have to be removed but always keeping the counter at 1

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class AutoRole(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client=client

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("AutoRole: ON")

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self,payload):
        messageID = 874997842748506112
        if messageID == payload.message_id:
            member = payload.member
            guild = member.guild
            emoji = payload.emoji.name
            if emoji == '❤️':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Red")
            elif emoji == '':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Yellow")
            await member.add_roles(role)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self,payload):
        messageID = 874997842748506112
        if messageID == payload.message_id:
            guild = await(self.client.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id))
            emoji = payload.emoji.name
            if emoji == '❤️':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Red")
            elif emoji == '':
                role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Yellow")
            member = await(guild.fetch_member(payload.user_id))
            if member is not None:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
            else:
                print("Member not found")


    @commands.command()
    async def Modulo_AutoRole(self, ctx):
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Title",
            description="Description",
            color=0x1abc9c
        )
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction('❤️')
        await msg.add_reaction('')

def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(AutoRole(client))
```

Comment: Id say, a more intuitive way is to not remove the reaction. If the user has an "active" reaction, they have the role. If they remove their reaction, their role will be removed. Like a On/Off switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the bot to remove the reaction from the message after their role has been assigned to them you add something like this to your code in `on_raw_reaction_add` after you assign the role.

```py
msg = await self.bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id).fetch_message(payload.message_id)
await msg.remove_reaction(reaction, payload.member)
```

However because you want the emoji counter to stay at 1 (just the bot), you won't be able to have `on_raw_reaction_remove`. I'd make the `on_raw_reaction_add` method check the `payload.member` has the role, add it if they don't, and remove it if they do, then remove the reaction. Also another thing, while this isn't required, it's recommend to check the reaction was added by a bot (`payload.member.bot`)

Right after you get the role `role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Red")`, check if the user has the role like this:

```py
role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Red")
has_role = False
for user_role in payload.member.roles:
     if role.id == user_role.id:
          has_role = True
if has_role:
     await payload.member.remove_roles(role)
else:
     await payload.member.add_roles(role)
```

The code above goes through all the roles the member has and checks if they have the role (`has_role`).

If they don't have the role (`has_role` is False), then the bot adds the role.

If they do have the role (`has_role` is True), then the bot removes the role from the Member.

Comment: *"I'd make the on_raw_reaction_add method check the payload.member has the role, add it if they don't, and remove it if they do, then remove the reaction."* i did not understand this point, could you give an example of the code?

Comment: Fantastic! Glad I could help.